# JIRA: How to give users permissions to create projects

Tags: jira

I installed JIRA 7.x and it all works fine. As admin i can create projects and so on. But i can't find the option to set the permission to create a project to some user. I checked all permissons, but if i login as normal user (which should have the right to browse projects) he can't create projects. The user only sees projects and can create issues.

Is there any other option to set, so that the user can create a project?

What i want is, that i will create a project role "Project Admin" which are only project leaders has. Only this group should be able to create projects.

Can anyone tell me, how to do this?

Thanks

Comment: This sounds like https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/JRA-3156, one of two infamous most-voted issues in JIRA that have been open for 12+ years without being meaningfully addressed by Atlassian.

Comment: Okay, so there is currently no solution?

Comment: We've created a plugin - self service that allows any user to create projects from predefined templates

Comment: @SvetlinZarev: is that plugin public? Whats the name or can you gave it to me?

Comment: @Tobi no, it's not public, but it should not be difficult to create your own: https://docs.atlassian.com/jira/latest/com/atlassian/jira/project/ProjectManager.html#createProject-com.atlassian.jira.user.ApplicationUser-com.atlassian.jira.bc.project.ProjectCreationData-

Comment: @SvetlinZarev: can you gave that plugin to me? Can I write you an email?

Comment: I'm sorry but it's my company's property and I cannot give it to you. But as I said it's enough to create a simple JSP that calls the method from my previous comment.

Answer (score 0):

You can't using the JIRA built in features, however you can use https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/com.wittified.jira.project-creator/server/overview to do this (disclaimer: I work for the company that builds/maintains this add-on).